# Xcode workspace schemes definition

Tags: ios, xcode

There is a nice command that lists all schemes in a Xcode workspace:

```
xcodebuild -workspace PATH -list
```

How to extract this list programmatically without xcodebuild? It should be stored somewhere in Xcode project files. But I can't find it inside xcworkspace. For example, in [this project](https://github.com/chroman/Doppio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the schemes are in the xcuserdata -- lone file per scheme

they are build on the fly if they don't exist. (e.g. if that folder wasn't checked in like in that repo)
To build them just enum all targets

the exception being shared schemes: they also come as 1 file per scheme but are in xcshareddata directory.

---

enum those files to get the schemes. if they don't exist, the user never ran Xcode

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. The question is how Xcode generate those schemes based on files in repository.

Comment: I don't get it.. if the files aren't there, there are no schemes. if you want, enum all targets in that case. because that;s default: 1 scheme for each  target.

Comment: The question is how exactly "xcodebuild -list" works. It doesn't use xcuserdata file. It grabs the data from xcodeproject as I assume. But what is the exact algorithm?

It's more a question about Xcode project file formats.

Comment: the algorithm is simply `foreach target in xcodeFile_xml; scheme=scheme_from_target`

Comment: but as I said this is only true when there are no user-made / customised schemes

Comment: What I was looking for is how Xcode creates schemes when there are no scheme file. As I understand it creates one scheme per target.